# Using a packaged linked via npm link in create-react-app leads to webpack error: module has no exports

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, npm-link

I am developing a React hook locally, and trying to test it in an adjacent create-react-app project (under folder `example/`). However, importing said linked module results in the following errors:

```bash
Attempted import error: 'usePleaseStay' is not exported from 'react-use-please-stay' (imported as 'usePleaseStay').
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 10:2-15
export 'usePleaseStay' (imported as 'usePleaseStay') was not found in 'react-use-please-stay' (module has no exports)

ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 14:10-23
export 'usePleaseStay' (imported as 'usePleaseStay') was not found in 'react-use-please-stay' (module has no exports)
```

My App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { usePleaseStay } from 'react-use-please-stay';

function App() {
  usePleaseStay(["Title One!", "Title Two!", "Title Three?!?"]);
  return (
    <></>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The file I'm brought to when I cmd+click `react-use-please-stay`:

```
export { usePleaseStay } from './hooks/usePleaseStay';
```

This is as expected, correctly the `dist/index.d.ts` file from my hook's source code. Clearly, there is an export there!

Output of `npm ls --location=global --depth=0 --link=true`:

```
react-use-please-stay@1.0.0 -> ./../../../../../projects/react-use-please-stay
```

What in the world is going on here? Is this the classic issue of `create-react-app` obfuscating too many webpack decisions from us?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out. Was just a one liner. I was packaging my module to Common JS. This doesn't play nicely with `create-react-app`'s Webpack config. I resolve the issue by changing my rollup.config.js from:

```js
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import pkg from './package.json' assert { type: "json" };

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: {
    file: pkg.main,
    format: 'cjs',
    sourcemap: true,
    strict: false,
  },
  plugins: [typescript()],
  external: ['react']
};
```

to:

```js
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import pkg from './package.json' assert { type: "json" };

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: {
    file: pkg.main,
    format: 'module',
    sourcemap: true,
    strict: false,
  },
  plugins: [typescript()],
  external: ['react']
};
```

Just changing `format: 'cjs'` to `format: 'module'`